# accessing docker private registry

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry, docker-machine

I have my private docker registry running on a remote machine, which is secured by TLS and uses HTTPS. Now I want to access it from my local docker-machine installed on Windows 7. I have copied the certificates to "/etc/docker/certs.d/" in the docker-machine VM and restarted docker.

After this I can successfully login to my private registry using credentials, but when I try to push an image to it, it gives me a `certificate signed by unknown authority` error. After researching a little I restarted the docker daemon with `docker -d --insecure-registry https://<registry-host>`, and it worked.

My question is: if I have copied my certificates to the host machine, why do I need to start the registry with the `--insecure-registry` option?

I can only access the registry from another host with certificates as well as restarting docker with `--insecure-registry` , which looks a little wrong to me.

Docker version: 1.8.3

Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> certificate signed by unknown authority

The error message gives it away - your certificates are self-signed (as in not trusted by a known CA).

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/).

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for response, in the link it is mentioned "you can also run registry on HTTP" , but in this case I am not able to access it at all from other hosts, then only I decided to create certificates. 
can we not use registry from other hosts just with plain HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access your registry with HTTP, follow the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Basically (do this on the machine `from` which you try to access the registry):

1. edit the file /etc/default/docker so that there is a line that reads: `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry myregistrydomain.com:5000"` (or add that to existing DOCKER_OPTS)
2. restart your Docker daemon: on ubuntu, this is usually `service docker stop` && `service docker start`

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the response but I have tried that and it doesn't work for me :( is there something to do with the docker version? because I read somewhere only HTTP authentication is not supported after docker version 1.3. please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @gya I have Docker version 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7 and it works for me